# Changing names of variables in randomForest object

Tags: r, raster, random-forest, prediction, r-raster

I want to predict a `randomForest` object to a huge `RasterStack`.
The `randomForest`object was trained with a `dataframe` with vairables named like "05_absor_1", "05_absor_2" ...
The `RasterStack` has 189 layers, which are names like "X05_absor_1", "X05_absor_2" ...
I tried to change the names of the layers of the `RasterStack`, but, as it occurs, they cannot be named beginning with a number.

Is there any possibility to adapt these two data sets to each other by renaming the variable names of the `RandomForest` object?

Comment: what about renaming the columns of your training data set?

Comment: Yes that would work, but the training takes a very long time, so I thought I could work around that.

Comment: Could you post a `str(ofYourRasterStack)`, maybe there is a way tho set the names by hand.

Comment: You can't rename variables of the randomforest object. Changing you data columns' names is the only way.

Comment: Either that or you can recreate the object with renaming the columns of your `dataframe`

Comment: @drmariod the `str()` would be too much. But here is the   
`> head(names(teststack))  
[1] "X05_absor_mean"          "X05_absor_variance"      "X05_absor_homogeneity"   "X05_absor_contrast"      "X05_absor_dissimilairty"
[6] "X05_absor_entropy" `

Comment: So, is `names(teststack) <- sub('^X', '', names(teststack))` not working?

Comment: no, unfortunately not.

Comment: I haven't worked with raster objects before, but from the documentation it looks like you have to find a way to turn your RasterStack into a data frame first; `predict.randomForest()` won't recognize it otherwise. I don't know how to do that conversion. Once that's done, though, then you should have no trouble renaming the variables with something like `names(teststack) <- substr(names(teststack), 2, nchar(names(teststack)))`.

Comment: Check `?make.names` {base}

Answer (score 1):

Better late then never

You can't rename the variables in the randomForest object, but you can extract the Raster stack. Then you can change the colnames, predict the model on the exracted dataframe. At the end you can overwrite the raster cell values of one rasterlayer in the stack with the values of the predicted data frame. This will present your prediciton on the raster stack.

Look at this post, facing a similar issue with spaces in the model variable names:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/66301739/13440906